# Is there a way to use fingerprint scanner not with touchid api

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I have a use case of 2 users with same Iphone.
Both have access using touchId.

I want to add authentication to my app, but i only want one of the users to have access.

Is there a way to build my own fingerprint authentication?
Or to give the user a choice of what finger print from TouchId will work?

Thanks

Comment: you can use this `give the user a choice of what finger print from TouchId will work`

Comment: initially add the any primary id , related to that finger print, second time fetch from details from keychain and show in the list on user which type of the need

Comment: what to you mean by adding a primary key? 
I cant find any documentation for getting and choosing fingerprints from touch id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to build your own fingerprint authentication (at least by using public API). Also there is no way to give user a choice of what finger print from TouchId will work.
Notice, that you do not specify which fingerprint you are providing during adding one.

LocalAuthentication provides you only `true`/`false` value if fingerprint is/isn't recognised.

If you want to distinguish users you have to provide login/password based authorisation.

Comment: you _do_ have the ability to give a unique nickname to each fingerprint on your phone. that information could certainly be provided via api without security risk. (however it is not)

Comment: Yes in theory this is possible (I would call it a `label` rather than `nickname`) but not without security risk. Consider the situation when you have two fingerprint with labels 'A' and 'B' and you use it to authenticate in the app to two accounts. User with fingerprint `A` can change only the label to `B`. Yes, some internal identifier probably won't change but this is also risky, because if you remove fingerprint and add the new one, even for the same finger, this identifier will be lost too.